# How to display a dynamic graph plot on ipad using Xcode

Tags: xcode, ipad, graph, plot

I am learning how to develop for the ipad and I have a pretty big project to do.

I already have screens and buttons loaded on the ipad via IOS simulator, xcode and interface builder. My next task is to display a graph on the ipad that is updating its plots and points every 30 seconds or so.

If you've ever heard of California ISO, it shows peak demand for electricity in the united states  http://www.caiso.com/outlook/SystemStatus.html       and I basically want to create a graph that represents data in a similar way: it updates by itself on the ipad.

Again I am using xcode and interface builder. I don't know where to begin at all haha

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Answer (score 0):

Call `-reloadData` on your graph whenever you have new data to display. It will query your datasource for the new data and redraw the plots.